# please help me replace string pattern with jquery

Tags: jquery, pattern-matching

using a twitter display widget and need to add links to the hash tags. so i need a pattern replacement, replacing each string that starts with a hash/pound sign and ends in a space with the twitter search link. i am pretty clumsy w/jquery--can someone point me in the right direction -- thanks, anyone!

something taking me:

```
// FROM:
<ul id="tweets">
     <li>Some nutty tweet. #nutty</li>
     <li>A fruity tweet here. #fruity</li>
</ul>

// TO:
<ul id="tweets">
     <li>Some nutty tweet. <a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23nutty">#nutty</a></li>
     <li>A fruity tweet here. http://twitter.com/search?q=%23fruity">#fruity</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey @wagner, if my answer was what you used to solve the problem, you might want to mark it "solved". We both get rep and future searchers will have more faith in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, I would recommend the [jQuery Tweetify Text](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-tweetify-text/) from the CSS-Snippets library.

You would then use it like this (given your code):

```
$("#tweets li").tweetify();
```

In addition to matching `#hashes`, it also turns URL's into hyperlinks, and matches `@username` and links to their profile.

Comment: thanks!  while i can't use that exactly because of some other restrictions, it's a great example for the replacement i need.  thanks again!